# Rails Associations for Hierarchical Cataloging / Taxonomy

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rdbms

I'm curious how best to reproduce a typical category hierarchy in rails.

By hierarchy I simply mean

`parent_node > child_node > sub_child_node > sub_sub_child_node`

Right now I have things set up something like this:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one  :child_node,      -> { where(root:  true) }      
  has_many :sub_child_nodes, -> { where(root: false) }
end
```

A boolean flag that indicates a top-level parent or not, but this does not account for deeply-nested nodes or their relationships to each other or with "parents". What would you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [`ancestry`](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) or [`acts_as_tree`](https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree).